# JDBC / MySQL query and update in a transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, transactions, locking

Basically our user provisioning algorithm does something like

-query for a new user
-update database to show you have that user

I'm wondering how to lock the ability for other instances of the process to do the "read" step while one has already started.  So it's a little more aggressive than a typical transaction, because it needs to be a read-read lock, and of course unrelated processes should be able to read without being affected by the lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply run the UPDATE query immediately to "steal" all inactive users for the current server.

Since individual UPDATE queries are always atomic, this will ensure that each user is only grabbed by one server.

Since MySQL does not allow you to return the updated rows from an UPDATE, you will need to add an identifier column to tell you which rows were "stolen".
Every time you provision users, pick a GUID, set the identifier column to that GUID in the UPDATE statement, then SELECT rows WHERE they still have that GUID.

Comment: This actually solves the problem - I'll leave the question open just because I'm curious to learn more about how to use MySQL transaction-related features to solve this.